# Offline Speech to text in Android?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I would like to do an application in android which translates speech from incoming call to text. Since i cant connect to mobile data while on call, i have to do the conversion offline.. Is it possible? Can I use any API or libraries to do it? Also is there any restrictions in tapping incoming voice? Please do reply..

Answer (score 0):

Regular apps can record the phone owner side of the conversation, but to also record the remote user's voice, you need to have root access as well as a kernel patch.

As far as voice transcription, I don't know of any api you could use for free straight from the phone (assuming you get the recorded audio).